# Troubles calculating a set infimum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have a set like this one:

$$A=\left\{\sqrt{x^2+x}-x, x \in \Re\right\}$$

I am trying to calculate the infimum, which seeing a plot drawn with wolfram has been revealed to be zero (for x=0).

So I try to calculate if this inequality may be true for all values of x in some interval:

$$\sqrt{x^2+x}-x \ge d $$

It becomes:

$$x(1-2d) - d^2 \ge 0 $$
$$\Delta(d)= 4d^2 -4d +1$$

So it has a lower bound if ∆(d)<0 for some d values, for all x values. But ∆(d) may never be negative, it has only a zero. So according to this solution the set doesn't have a lower bound, but it has one !! What did I do wrong here?

PS: I am following a book which solves these problems without using a precise rule. What I need is the rule: is there a rule which says how to compute if a function has a lower/upper bound, and in case the infimum/supremum? I just see tricky ways to solve these problems, which I often understand, but I don't understand what pattern is followed to solve them, I don't see a precise algorithm. If someone knows material/books which explain this please post them, I haven't found anything of useful on the web.

PS: I need to solve it without using limits and derivatives, just with the method I've shown, if possible.

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for how to typeset common math expressions with MathJax.

Comment: I cannot follow your work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule to solve these kind of exercises is through the study of the function (limits, derivative, etc). However generally these exercises are carried out before one sees limits and derivatives...

In this particular case one understand that the function goes to zero as x->0 while it is clearly always positive.

Comment: Ok but I need to calculate a solution without using limits, and without guessing the result. True that I can guess it by just substituting the x, but I need the general rule.

Answer (score 0):

First note this, the function is defined on the [domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411430/sign-charts-and-expressed-in-interval-form/411460#411460) $ (-\infty,-1] \cup [0,\infty)$. Also you can see this $f(0)=0$, which what you want to prove, and $ f(-1)=1. $ Now, prove that the function is increasing on the interval $[0,\infty)$ and decreasing on $(-\infty,-1]$. Also, note that

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}-x=\frac{1}{2},\, \lim_{x\to -\infty}\sqrt{x^2+x}-x = \infty. $$

Comment: I know that this can be calculated with limits. But I am more concerned about knowing why I get wrong results with the solution I posted. Is there something wrong I do?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Limits are just only one part of the technique. As I said "you need to prove that the function decreases and increases on specified intervals".

Comment: I know that this would also use derivatives, but this is not how I am supposed to solve the problem. I would solve it with the technique that I shown in the question body. I fail to find what error I have done.

Answer (score 0):

We observe that $\sqrt{x^2+x}$ has meaning iff $x\geq 0$ or $x\leq-1$.

- If $x\geq 0$ then 
  $$
  \sqrt{x^2+x}-x\geq\sqrt{x^2}-x=0.
  $$
- If $x\leq -1$ then
  $$
  \sqrt{x^2+x}-x\geq 1>0.
  $$
  Hence
  $$
  \inf A=\min A=0.
  $$