# determine x in $x\log_\frac{1}{10}(x^2+x+1)>0$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, logarithms

I wanted to know, how can i determine the values of x for which

> $x\log_\frac{1}{10}(x^2+x+1)>0$

going to the question, we must have $x>0$ and $\log_\frac{1}{10}(x^2+x+1)>0$ or both must be smaller than zero. How can i solve for $\log_\frac{1}{10}(x^2+x+1)$ to be greater than or smaller than 0.

Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Remember change of base formula $\log_b a= \log_c a / \log_c b$. From that conclude that for $0<b<1$ we have $\log_b a>0\ $ if $\ 0<a<1$

Answer (score 1):

Note that,

$$ \log_{a} 1 = 0 \implies x^2+x+1 > 1 .$$

See here for a [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411430/sign-charts-and-expressed-in-interval-form/411460#411460).

Comment: @Shobhit: see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411430/sign-charts-and-expressed-in-interval-form/411460#411460).

Answer (score 1):

Base $1/10$ is confusing to me: I am accustomed to base $e$, or $10$, or $2$.

But note that $\log_{1/10} a=-\log_{10} a$, so we want to find out where $x\log_{10}(x^2+x+1)\lt 0$.

Note that $x^2+x+1$ is always positive, since it can be written as $(x+1/2)^2+3/4$.

So our function $x\log_{10}(x^2+x+1$ is defined everywhere. Let's find out where it is $0$. Clearly at $0$, and also where $\log_{10}(x^2+x+1)=0$, that is, where $x^2+x+1=1$. This happens at $x=0$ and at $x=-1$.

The function can only change sign at most at the places $-1$ and $0$. So we have three intervals to worry about: (i) $(-\infty,-1)$; (ii) $(-1,0)$; and (iii) $(0,\infty)$.

Now use **test points** to determine the (unchanging) sign in each interval.

On the interal $(-\infty, -1)$, you could pick a test point, like $x=-10$, and (even) use your calculator to find the sign of the function there. But my calculator has a bad battery. Without it, it is obvious that $x^2+x+1$ is kind of big at $x=-10$, so the log is positive, and then the $x$ in front makes the whole thing negative.

Similarly, even without a calculator, it is clear that if $x$ is big positive, then our function is positive.

It remains to investigate the interval $(-1,0)$. Here if you wish you can use your calculator to determine the sign of $x\log_{10}(x^2+x+1)$, by say using the test point $x=-1/2$. But we don't need a calculator, since at $x=-1/2$, we have $x^2+x+1=3/4$, which has a negative log to the base $10$. Multiplying by $x$ gives us a positive number.

Conclusion: The interval on which $x\log_{10}(x^2+x+1)$ is **negative** is $(-\infty,-1)$. This is the answer to the question about where $x\log_{1/10}(x^2+x+1)$
is **positive**.

**Remark:** It could all be done without the switch to base $10$, and you may prefer to do it that way. Basically the same argument, just greater chance of error.